# Nominal subject clauses

Tags: clauses, subjects

To emphasise a particular information in a sentence we put a *what* clause followed by the appropriate form of the verb *be*:

> 1. *We are looking for volunteers*.
>      » *What we are looking for **is** volunteers.*
> 2. *I really like action films*.
>      » *What I really like **is** action films.*

Is this a formal way by using ***is*** instead of ***are***? Or is it because if we used two ***are*** at the end would it be redundant?

Comment: Oh +1, actually this is an interesting question. Whether "what" should be considered plural, or singular in this case.

Comment: Related question **[“What makes her laugh IS …” or “What makes her laugh ARE …” - plural or singular?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49702/what-makes-her-laugh-is-or-what-makes-her-laugh-are-plural-or-sing)**

Comment: Another related question: **[What my son likes the best on TV (are/is) cartoons?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68574/what-my-son-likes-the-best-on-tv-are-is-cartoons?lq=1)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@CopperKettle's answer in the linked question is definitely relevant here. Quoted below:

> "What makes her laugh are dirty jokes."
>
> The meaning: We hear her laughing right now. We both know that she is laughing right now because she has just heard some jokes. I want to say to you that in my view the jokes she is laughing to are dirty.
>
> "What makes her laugh is dirty jokes."
>
> The meaning: When she hears dirty jokes, she usually laughs.

Some trustworthy-looking references are provided for this. I think this sounds pretty reasonable in terms of "strictly correct" grammar.

However, what I can say as a native speaker of American English is that the examples with "are" *always* sound wrong to me. When "what" is used as a pronoun, it is always singular. Note that the verb agrees with the *subject*, so when "what" is not the subject, the verb may be plural. For example:

> What we are looking for **is** volunteers.

vs.

> Volunteers **are** what we are looking for.

When phrased as a question, "what" does not function as the subject:

> What **are** you looking for?

Means

> You **are** looking for what?

One of the things to recognize here is that you can say "[singular noun] is [plural noun]" or "[plural noun] are [singular noun]". It is *not* necessary for both nouns to agree. For example:

> **The thing** I like most about France **is the pastries**.
>
> **Games are** my favorite **way** to pass the time.

Answer (score 0):

The use of plural verb are/were before plural nouns, such as are in the sentences presented,  is common, though some people say we should use "is'.

I think the use of " is" is more appropriate grammatically. Look at the sentence taken from Longman.

What matters is the British people and British jobs.